# Looking for Java method to bundle multiple button image data in one file

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a javaFx based POS system that will receive input via a touch screen monitor.  The input screen will have lots of buttons (50+) with different image data on each button.  I have been looking for a method to contain all these graphic images (small 75x75px) in one file that can be read at startup instead of opening 50 different image files.  I imagine that this will speed up the start up process.

I have looked at java resource bundles as a method but it looks like this system is designed to store local specific content and it seems like it would be complex to implement for my needs.

I am wondering if anyone knows of some java or javaFx utilities or routines that would be suited to this problem.  Maybe something where I could load all the image data, store it in some object, and then write this object out on one file.  Maybe some sort of dictionary object that I could just write out to a file and then read back in on startup.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually profiled your system to see if that's why it's slow?

Comment: I haven't written the software yet; I was just thinking that opening and reading one file would be superior to opening 50+ small files.  Plus, I wouldn't have to keep track of all the little files.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. " -Donald Knuth

Comment: I know; but it is my nature.  And, in my opinion, folks often get to zealous about not worrying about small efficiencies.  I guess I am looking for a little more elegant solution than reading in a bunch of little files.  These are all arbitrary preferences.  Your point is well taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@FXML
private Button btn1;

    Image img = new Image("/images/2013-07-14_14-40-17_89.jpg");

        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        iv.setImage(img);
        Rectangle2D viewportRect = new Rectangle2D(100, 250, 50, 50);
        iv.setViewport(viewportRect);
        btn1.setGraphic(iv);
```

You can load one Image and create an ImageView (a Node) for every button. The ImageView picks a view port rectangle inside the large image.

---

To create a single file from several images, something like:

```
 BufferedImage totalImage = new BufferedImage(...);
 Graphics2D g = totalImage.createGraphics();
 String[] files = { ... };
 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
     BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(files[i]);
     int x = i * 75;
     int y = 0;
     g.drawImage(x, y, img, ...);
 }
 ImageIO.write(totalImage, ...);
 g.dispose();
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea and would seem to accomplish what I want.  Do you know of a slick way to build this file--to create a large image from a bunch of little ones?

Comment: As I am still not comfortable with all in-and-outs of JavaFX, I would use ImageIO, an ImageBuffer and so on.